# I am using expressjs and when I heroku deploy my site going to cruch

Tags: mongodb, express, heroku, heroku-cli

I am trying to deploy my project on hreoku but I got the error

`2022-05-20T07:45:17.754377+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=agro-log.herokuapp.com request_id=80aa6ef2-1c4c-4541-aaf5-c54e8b0cdec5 fwd="103.151.119.18" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https`

[problem showing om Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYEo9.png)

**I as also trying chenage my port but It's not working**

```
 const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Our app is running on port ${ PORT }`);
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYEo9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please add a root endpoint for the application.

something like

```
app.get("/", (req,res)=>{
 res.send({message:"hello world"})
})
```

Comment: I have used it on my index.js file where I create API but everything is alright on my local node server the problem starts when I deploy on heroku's website. you might see the img which attached to the problem.

Comment: There is a way to see those logs. please read them and see